# Javascript make table with rows and columns given by user and change each cells colour onclick

Tags: javascript

I have a code in which the user enters the number of rows and columns. the table of given rows and columns are created with each cell has an event of onClick, where the user clicks on any cell and the background color of the cell changes. in my code how do I change the background color of the cell?

```
<body>
    Grid Height:
        <input id="n1" type="number" name="height" min="1" value="1">
    Grid Width:
        <input id="n2" type="number" name="width" min="1" value="1">
    <input type="submit" onclick="makegrid()">
    <table width="100px" height="100px" id="myTable" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse" >
    </table>
  <script>
        var x,rn,cn;

        function makegrid()// function called after submit button is clicked
        {
            rn = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value); //fetches the entered rows by user
            cn = parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value); //fetches the entered column by user

            for(var r=0;r<rn;r++)
            {
                x=document.getElementById("myTable").insertRow(r); //insert row to the table
                for(var c=0;c<cn;c++)  
                {
                   var y= x.insertCell(c); //insert cells to each row
                }

            }
          }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `click` listener to the document, check if the clicked element is `td` if yes change the background color of cell.

```js
var x, rn, cn;

function makegrid() // function called after submit button is clicked
{
  rn = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value); //fetches the entered rows by user
  cn = parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value); //fetches the entered column by user

  for (var r = 0; r < rn; r++) {
    x = document.getElementById("myTable").insertRow(r); //insert row to the table
    for (var c = 0; c < cn; c++) {
      var y = x.insertCell(c); //insert cells to each row
    }

  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
  if (target.tagName == "TD") {
    target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
});
```

```html
Grid Height:
<input id="n1" type="number" name="height" min="1" value="1"> Grid Width:
<input id="n2" type="number" name="width" min="1" value="1">
<input type="submit" onclick="makegrid()">
<table width="100px" height="100px" id="myTable" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
</table>
```